# Rails 7 connect to Twitter API strict-origin-when-cross-origin error

Tags: twitter-oauth, content-security-policy, ruby-on-rails-7

Context: attempting to connect to twitter API Oauth2 version,  after submitting twice, both with and without the following block  `initializers/content_security_policy.rb`

```
 Rails.application.configure do
   config.content_security_policy do |policy|
     policy.default_src :self, :https
     policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
     policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
     policy.object_src  :none
     policy.script_src  :self, :https
     policy.style_src   :self, :https
#     # Specify URI for violation reports
#     # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
   end
 end
```

via the following rendered rails code to HTML form

```
<%= form_tag('/auth/twitter2', method: 'post', data: {turbo: false}) do %>
  <button type='submit'>Login with Twitter</button>
<% end %>

<form data-turbo="false" action="/auth/twitter2" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="mU-GNjvKcWumrWZME_EszVTvi5wxo_5si89wOyCzCM0_SOmjAWQp1Vb8Gey71T1vCkRE9hahDd7r5zLpip1d_A" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit">Login with Twitter</button>
</form>
```

The same was attempted with both a localhost:3000 host and an ngrok.io host
The console for the browser complains with the data at bottom.

Notes:
• the client ID is correct as set in the credentials
• the redirect_url has a slash removed from the string, yet it is present in the Twitter developer console `https://https://170-343e-5-92-35.eu.ngrok.io/auth/twitter2/callback.eu.ngrok.io/auth/twitter2/callback`
• twitter seems to recognize an active user `x-twitter-active-user`

It appears the API recognizes user but returns an error for lack of a security policy.

Yet something is wrong / missing here.  What is it?

gems used are:

```
  gem "omniauth", "~> 2.1"
  gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~> 1.0"
  gem "omniauth-twitter2", "~> 0.1.0"
```

```
XHR GET https://twitter.com/i/api/2/oauth2/authorize?code_challenge=VqpkyR0-V1CTxnWXCdv0GCN_YP0fxX4JG0CggNxzDlo&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=QkNaZGYxdXV2VVBteUhOZnZDZmQ6MTpjaQ&redirect_uri=https://170-343e-5-92-35.eu.ngrok.ioauth/twitter2/callback&response_type=code&scope=tweet.read users.read&state=274c1aa25c3274500095c77115cb4acc246fb9615e82f81a
[HTTP/2 400 Bad Request 187ms]

    
GET
    
scheme  
    https  
host  
    twitter.com  
filename  
    /i/api/2/oauth2/authorize  
code_challenge  
    VqpkyR0-V1CTxnWXCdv0GCN_YP0fxX4JG0CggNxzDlo  
code_challenge_method  
    S256  
client_id  
    XV2VhQkNaZGYxdOZVBteUnZDZmQ6MTpjaQ  
redirect_uri  
    https://170-343e-5-92-35.eu.ngrok.ioauth/twitter2/callback  
response_type  
    code  
scope  
    tweet.read users.read  
state  
    274c1aa25c3274500095c77115cb4acc246fb9615e82f81a  
Address  
    104.244.42.129:443

Status
400
Bad Request
Version HTTP/2
Transferred 706 B (132 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin

        
    cache-control
        no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
    content-disposition
        attachment; filename=json.json
    content-encoding
        gzip
    content-length
        128
    content-type
        application/json;charset=UTF-8
    date
        Mon, 31 Oct 2022 13:20:46 GMT
    perf
        7626143928
    server
        tsa_o
    strict-transport-security
        max-age=631138519
    x-connection-hash
        97ae1535e53b9ac87a0e6dc13996c3433bbbbaa470309893496090c60964af9d
    x-content-type-options
        nosniff
    X-Firefox-Spdy
        h2
    x-frame-options
        SAMEORIGIN
    x-response-time
        137
    x-transaction-id
        51c8c8c80424d52b
    x-xss-protection
        0
        
    Accept
        */*
    Accept-Encoding
        gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language
        en-US,en;q=0.5
    authorization
        Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA
    Connection
        keep-alive
    Cookie
        guest_id=v1%3A165780214435378276; ct0=4020832aeed06194a4a62c8e5cc444311104716913ea7dcd10c30bb3dccfc87204d0ecf06771c5be6912634af55dd73edef992ae81eb79b1f507c8a79a50723aa018762a63ce9bca4aac58de0c35aedf; d_prefs=MjoxLGNvbnNlbnRfdmVyc2lvbjoyLHRleHRfdmVyc2lvbjoxMDAw; kdt=IZm9EbuU31Z5S5qEyVo0YPtSiIgF8djIWpHREbzq; twid=u%3D829665148143022080; auth_token=615b92f058b05ed8cd8829494d9421c5bb35a34a; night_mode=2; eu_cn=1; _twitter_sess=BAh7CyIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCPgH%252FvyBAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlYmQ2YjVhYWNkYTYyZTQyYjI1YjEzNzkwYWM0MThmNWE6B2lkIiUyMjg0%250AZWZkZDMzZjcwMGU2NjVmMjhmNDY4Yzc3ZGI4NjofbGFzdF9wYXNzd29yZF9j%250Ab25maXJtYXRpb24iFTE2NjcyMDY2MjM0ODkwMDA6HnBhc3N3b3JkX2NvbmZp%250Acm1hdGlvbl91aWQiFzgyOTY2NTE0ODE0MzAyMjA4MA%253D%253D--bf686a94467ee3b422f132c9b1b181de4480d7e6; des_opt_in=N
    DNT
        1
    Host
        twitter.com
    Referer
        https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?client_id=QkNaZGYxdXV2VVBteUhOZnZDZmQ6MTpjaQ&code_challenge=VqpkyR0-V1CTxnWXCdv0GCN_YP0fxX4JG0CggNxzDlo&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F170-343e-5-92-35.eu.ngrok.ioauth%2Ftwitter2%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=tweet.read+users.read&state=274c1aa25c3274500095c77115cb4acc246fb9615e82f81a
    Sec-Fetch-Dest
        empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode
        cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site
        same-origin
    TE
        trailers
    User-Agent
        Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
    x-csrf-token
        4020832aeed06194a4a62c8e5cc444311104716913ea7dcd10c30bb3dccfc87204d0ecf06771c5be6912634af55dd73edef992ae81eb79b1f507c8a79a50723aa018762a63ce9bca4aac58de0c35aedf
    x-twitter-active-user
        yes
    x-twitter-auth-type
        OAuth2Session
    x-twitter-client-language
        en
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another gem involved: `Devise`

Although  `config/initializers/devise.rb` did not include any references to
`config.omniauth :twitter2`  it still conflicted with the `omniauth` gem.

Removing `omniauth` was necessary, in addition to configuring the devise initializer, to properly connect with twitter provider (exactly `twitter2` for OAuth 2.0 connections).